# Filling Missing values Pandas Dataframe backward hourly/weekly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe which look like this

```
Code                   DIAG
Time
1999-12-01 00:00:01.870     None
1999-12-01 00:00:10.870     None
2000-01-01 09:10:09.870    None
2000-01-01 09:10:10.870    None
2000-01-01 09:00:10.940    None
2000-01-01 09:00:11.160    None
2000-01-01 09:00:11.640    None
2000-01-01 09:00:12.460    None
2010-01-01 09:00:34.910    1_19_1_4_0_0
2010-01-01 09:00:35.060    3_22_4_0_0_0
2010-01-01 09:00:35.120    6_22_10_3_0_0
```

I want to backfill the missing data only for one hour before each data and change the label so the data should look like something like this

```
Code                             DIAG
    Time
    1999-12-01 00:00:01.870     None
    1999-12-01 00:00:10.870     None
    2000-01-01 09:10:09.870    1_19_1_4_0_0_H
    2000-01-01 09:10:10.870    1_19_1_4_0_0_H
    2000-01-01 09:00:10.940    1_19_1_4_0_0_H
    2000-01-01 09:00:11.160    1_19_1_4_0_0_H
    2000-01-01 09:00:11.640    1_19_1_4_0_0_H
    2000-01-01 09:00:12.460    1_19_1_4_0_0_H
    2010-01-01 09:00:34.910    1_19_1_4_0_0_H
    2010-01-01 09:00:35.060    3_22_4_0_0_0
    2010-01-01 09:00:35.120    6_22_10_3_0_0
```

I wrote this code and it look like this:

```
def FillData(dff):
        s=dff.bfill()
        s.loc[s.notnull()]=s.astype('str').astype('str')+'_H'
        return s

    df=A['DIAG'].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='H')).apply(FillData)
```

The issue is that this is producing out put which is look like this:

```
Code                             DIAG
    Time
    1999-12-01 00:00:01.870     None
    1999-12-01 00:00:10.870     None
    2000-01-01 09:10:09.870    None
    2000-01-01 09:10:10.870    None
    2000-01-01 09:00:10.940    None
    2000-01-01 09:00:11.160    None
    2000-01-01 09:00:11.640    None
    2000-01-01 09:00:34.460    1_19_1_4_0_0_H
    2010-01-01 09:00:34.910    1_19_1_4_0_0_H
    2010-01-01 09:00:35.060    3_22_4_0_0_0_H
    2010-01-01 09:00:35.120    6_22_10_3_0_0_H
```

I see two main issue one is that groupby is not grouping by H and is only grouping by minute. The other issue is that is that it is adding label(_H) to all row. my main goal is to label the data 1 hour before it happen with _H and 1 week before they happen by _W.

I appreciate if any one can help me with this, I spent a lot of time on it but I cant find straight forward way to it.

Thanks